# Google appscript sending duplicate emails

Tags: google-apps-script

this is the code in the script:

```
sendSubmissionEmail();

function sendSubmissionEmail() {

  var consultantEmail = 'example@staffingprojects.co.za';

  {
   var subject = 'New Submission Notification - Example' ;
   var message = 'Hello, a new form has been submitted!';
  }
    // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(consultantEmail, subject, message);
}
```

It is set up to trigger from the submit on a form, but sends duplicate mails every time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the same problem because you have a function call in the script and then you call it from the trigger.

Try to get rid of the function call and you should be good. Try something like this:

```js
//sendSubmissionEmail();

function sendSubmissionEmail() {

  var consultantEmail = 'example@example.com';

  {
   var subject = 'New Submission Notification - Example' ;
   var message = 'Hello, a new form has been submitted!';
  }
    // Send the email
  MailApp.sendEmail(consultantEmail, subject, message);
}
```

If this fix doesn't solve your problem you should provide more information about how you have set up your triggers.